# Can I redistribute libmat.dll with my Program?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I have program that is reading and writing mat files using the Matlab API.
Therefore my only dependency ist on libmat.dll

Can i ship libmat.dll only (instead of requiring ~600mb MCR) or is that prohibited by a license?

Comment: Maybe throw out the proprietary library, use only MAT 7.3 (which is HDF5) and use an [open source library to read the files](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtainsrc.html#src).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you write `MAT` files out your code, you can...

Here are the terms from Matlab's `license.txt` (located in Matlab installation folder) under which you can deploy and share your `libmat.dll` linked application.

Excerpt from "Deployment Addendum" license section:

> 6. OTHER SOURCE CODE AND SHARED OBJECT CODE LIBRARIES.
>
>    6.1. Programs may include selected Source Code and shared Object Code
>         library files that implement various documented application
>         programming interface capabilities of the Programs for which the
>         Source Code or shared library file is part.
>
>    6.1.1. Licensed User may use and modify the selected Source Code files
>             solely for creation of Licensee's own Applications. Licensee may
>             copy and distribute Object Code compiled from this Source Code,
>             but only as either standalone Object Code file (regardless
>             whether a Derivative Form) or Object Code Linked to the
>             Application, and only for use with and deployment of Licensee's
>             own Application.
>
>    6.1.2. Licensee may use, copy and distribute shared Object Code library
>             files (regardless whether a Derivative Form) for deployment of
>             Licensee's own Application, but only if a header file exists in
>             the Program for the shared library file. Licensee may not copy or
>             distribute header files themselves.
>
>    6.1.3. Licensee may not transfer Source Code, development rights, or
>             development capabilities for any Source Code or Object Code to
>             any Third Party.
>
>    6.2. MAT-files.  Licensed User may create and distribute Applications that
>         read MAT-files using the MAT-file API, however, if such Applications
>         are distributed to Third Parties, they must also implement MAT-file
>         write capability.

Be aware that `libmat.dll` has its own further MATLAB library dependencies - so you'll need to ship also other Matlab DLLs in order to use `libmat.dll`.